# CMS for a blog in Python or Ruby?

Tags: cms, blog, ruby-on-rails, python

Which CMS **written in Ruby or Python** do you recommend me to choose for my blog? The requirements:

- being able to upload the images without having them cut their size
- comments (not really necessary as I can use discuss)
- themes
- free

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately as the question marked as a duplicate indicates, and [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in our Help Center, questions asking for CMS recommendations are considered off-topic since they can lead to spam, self-promotion, and opinion-based answers.

Comment: @dan, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: dan is right. However the other question doesn't have any answer related to Python and Ruby, so here is a link from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#Python)

Comment: @NikhilSupekar, if I found the answer in Wikipedia, I'd not ask the question here.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Please review [What topics can I ask about here?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Recommendations for all external resources are considered off-topic here, which is why there's a catch-all question for those asking for CMS recommendations.